# How do you get the pageYOffset of from the bottom of the window and not the top ( Javascript )?

Tags: javascript, iphone

I need to get the pageYOffset of the bottom of the viewable area, whether the user is zoomed in on the webpage or not, on Mobile Safari ( iPhone ).  However pageYOffset returns the offset from the *upper left corner of the window*.

Spec:

"pageYOffset properties returns the pixels the current document has been scrolled from the *upper left corner of the window*"

How do you get the page y offset from the bottom of the viewable area, (zoomed in or not) on the iPhone via Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

If you add window.availHeight to the YOffset it should give it to you.

Comment: window.availHeight comes back as 'undefined'.  window.screen.availHeight works but it gives you the same height if you are zoomed in or zoomed all of the way out.  Maybe there is something that gets the dimensions of the zoomed area in relation to the rest of the page.  Then you could add that to pageYOffset.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Zooming is not going to change the availHeight value because it is the number of pixels on the screen that does not change. I don't know of a property in the DOM that would return a usable value to you.